# Regular expression for splitting a comma with the string

Tags: c#-4.0

I had to split string data based on Comma.

This is the excel data:-
[Please find the excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akNpy.png)

string strCurrentLine="\"Himalayan Salt Body Scrub with Lychee Essential Oil from Majestic Pure, All Natural Scrub to Exfoliate & Moisturize Skin, 12 oz\",SKU_27,\"Tombow Dual Brush Pen Art Markers, Portrait, 6-Pack\",SKU_27,My Shopify Store 1,Valid,NonInventory".

Regex CSVParser = new Regex(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");
  string[] lstColumnValues = CSVParser.Split(strCurrentLine);

[I have attached the image.The problem is I used the Regex to split the string with comma but i need the ouptut just like SKU_27 because string[0] and string[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5R1Y.png) contains the forward and backward slash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5R1Y.png).I need the output string[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akNpy.png) and remove the forward and backward slash.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't attach text data as image, nobody will type it in. Also tell us more about your previous attempts to solve your problem, eg. you could paste code fragments etc.

Answer (score 0):

The file seems to be a CVA file. For CVA to be properly formatted, it will use quotes "" to wrap strings that contains comma, such as

> id, name, date
>   1,"Some text, that includes comma", 2020/01/01

Simply split the string by comma, you will get the 2nd column with double quote.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you are asking how to remove the double-quotes from `lstColumnValues[0]` and `lstColumnValues[2]`, or add them to `lstColumnValues[1]`.

To remove the double-quotes, just use `Replace`:

```
string myString = lstColumnValues[0].Replace("\"", "");
```

If you need to add them:

```
string myString = $"\"{lstColumnValues[1]}\"";
```